# How can I insert the contents of a shell command into my UNIX ed buffer?

Tags: shell, gnu, ed

I think I know how I can do this by writing to an external file, but I'm wondering if it's possible to directly insert the contents of a shell command into a UNIX `ed` buffer. I'm using GNU `ed` 1.15.

Thanks.

Comment: I see how I can do this via the r command in ed via a file, but I'm wondering if I can do this without resorting to an external file outside of the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I just do the `r` command followed by the shell command prefixed by a `!`. It's just like in `ex` or `vim`. You do: `r !cal` The above would append the result of the `cal` shell command into the `ed` buffer.